# Laplace transform of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, periodic-functions

Find the unique solution of $y''+ y = f$, $y(0) = y'(0) = 0$ with the $2\pi$ periodic function given by $f(t)=2\pi \sin(t)$.

I am having trouble setting up and starting the the question. I would be really grateful for any help or hints.

Comment: Do you remember the formulas for Laplace transforms of derivatives of a function? e.g. $L(f'(t))=sF(s)-f(0)$

Comment: Do you want to solve it with Laplace transform only?

Comment: Having trouble getting started? Take the Laplace transform of both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints;**

Take the Laplace transform on both sides. These ones may trouble you so here they are;

$$1)
\mathscr{L}_t [y''(t)](s)=s^2\mathscr{L}_t [y(t)](s)-sy(0)-y'(0)$$

$$2)
\mathscr{L}_t [2\pi\sin t](s)=2\pi\mathscr{L}_t [\sin t](s)=2\pi\times\frac{1}{s^2+1}$$

$$3)
\mathscr{L}_s^{-1} \left [\frac{2\pi}{(s^2+1)^2}\right ](t)=\pi\sin t-\pi t\cos t$$

$$4)
\mathscr{L}_s^{-1} \left [\frac{s}{s^2+1}\right ](t)=\cos t$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried taking Laplace transform of both sides but I ended up with totally different answer.

Comment: @Martin I cannot help if I don't see your work.

Comment: I managed to get up to number 3. How did you get 4? Sorry. I just started learning about Laplace transforms.

Comment: @Martin 4) is for inverting the $\frac{s y(0)}{s^2+1}$ term